# Application failed to launch in time... but it's only taking 2 seconds?

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, launch

Our application is crashing, and the crash log says;

```
Application Specific Information:
com.xxxx.xxxxx failed to launch in time 
elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 2.120 (user 1.200, system 0.920), 11% CPU 
elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.800, 4% CPU

...

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

I'm sure it can't be crashing out because it's taking **a whopping** 2 seconds to launch! Does anyone have any other ideas why we might be getting this message?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The two seconds are [CPU time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time), the elapsed real time was probably longer (with 11% CPU load, it would be more like 20 seconds).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

So I guess I just need to try and get my 'Did Finish Launching' function to be as lean as possible then?